# c# list permutations with limited length

Tags: c#, list, permutation

I have a list of Offers, from which I want to create "chains" (e.g. permutations) with limited chain lengths.

I've gotten as far as creating the permutations using the Kw.Combinatorics [project](https://kwcombinatorics.codeplex.com/.).
However, the default behavior creates permutations in the length of the list count. I'm not sure how to limit the chain lengths to 'n'.

Here's my current code:

```
    private static List<List<Offers>> GetPerms(List<Offers> list, int chainLength)
    {
        List<List<Offers>> response = new List<List<Offers>>();
        foreach (var row in new Permutation(list.Count).GetRows())
        {
            List<Offers> innerList = new List<Offers>();
            foreach (var mix in Permutation.Permute(row, list))
            {
                innerList.Add(mix);

            }
            response.Add(innerList);
            innerList = new List<Offers>();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Implemented by:

```
List<List<AdServer.Offers>> lst = GetPerms(offers, 2);
```

I'm not locked in KWCombinatorics if someone has a better solution to offer.

Comment: Could you not just replace `list.Count` with `chainLength`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking for a permutation, but for a variation. Here is a possible algorithm. I prefer iterator methods for functions that can potentially return very many elements. This way, the caller can decide if he really needs all elements:

```
IEnumerable<IList<T>> GetVariations<T>(IList<T> offers, int length)
{
    var startIndices = new int[length];
    var variationElements = new HashSet<T>(); //for duplicate detection

    while (startIndices[0] < offers.Count)
    {                
        var variation = new List<T>(length);
        var valid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            var element = offers[startIndices[i]];
            if (variationElements.Contains(element))
            {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
            variation.Add(element);
            variationElements.Add(element);
        }
        if (valid)
            yield return variation;

        //Count up the indices
        startIndices[length - 1]++;
        for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; --i)
        {
            if (startIndices[i] >= offers.Count)
            {
                startIndices[i] = 0;
                startIndices[i - 1]++;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        variationElements.Clear();
    }
}
```

The idea for this algorithm is to use a number in `offers.Count` base. For three offers, all digits are in the range 0-2. We then basically increment this number step by step and return the offers that reside at the specified indices. If you want to allow duplicates, you can remove the check and the `HashSet<T>`.

### Update

Here is an optimized variant that does the duplicate check on the index level. In my tests it is a lot faster than the previous variant:

```
IEnumerable<IList<T>> GetVariations<T>(IList<T> offers, int length)
{
    var startIndices = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        startIndices[i] = i;

    var indices = new HashSet<int>(); // for duplicate check

    while (startIndices[0] < offers.Count)
    {
        var variation = new List<T>(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            variation.Add(offers[startIndices[i]]);
        }
        yield return variation;

        //Count up the indices
        AddOne(startIndices, length - 1, offers.Count - 1);

        //duplicate check                
        var check = true;
        while (check)
        {
            indices.Clear();                    
            for (int i = 0; i <= length; ++i)
            {
                if (i == length)
                {
                    check = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (indices.Contains(startIndices[i]))
                {
                    var unchangedUpTo = AddOne(startIndices, i, offers.Count - 1);
                    indices.Clear();
                    for (int j = 0; j <= unchangedUpTo; ++j )
                    {
                        indices.Add(startIndices[j]);
                    }
                    int nextIndex = 0;
                    for(int j = unchangedUpTo + 1; j < length; ++j)
                    {
                        while (indices.Contains(nextIndex))
                            nextIndex++;
                        startIndices[j] = nextIndex++;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                indices.Add(startIndices[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int AddOne(int[] indices, int position, int maxElement)
{
    //returns the index of the last element that has not been changed

    indices[position]++;
    for (int i = position; i > 0; --i)
    {
        if (indices[i] > maxElement)
        {
            indices[i] = 0;
            indices[i - 1]++;
        }
        else
            return i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the very late response, but this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another implementation which I think should be faster than the accepted answer (and it's definitely less code).

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetVariationsWithoutDuplicates<T>(IList<T> items, int length)
{
  if (length == 0 || !items.Any()) return new List<List<T>> { new List<T>() };
  return from item in items.Distinct()
         from permutation in GetVariationsWithoutDuplicates(items.Where(i => !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(i, item)).ToList(), length - 1)
         select Prepend(item, permutation);
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetVariations<T>(IList<T> items, int length)
{
  if (length == 0 || !items.Any()) return new List<List<T>> { new List<T>() };
  return from item in items
         from permutation in GetVariations(Remove(item, items).ToList(), length - 1)
         select Prepend(item, permutation);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(T first, IEnumerable<T> rest)
{
  yield return first;
  foreach (var item in rest) yield return item;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Remove<T>(T item, IEnumerable<T> from)
{
  var isRemoved = false;
  foreach (var i in from)
  {
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, i) || isRemoved) yield return i;
    else isRemoved = true;
  }
}
```

On my 3.1 GHz Core 2 Duo, I tested with this:

```
public static void Test(Func<IList<int>, int, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>> getVariations)
{
  var max = 11;
  var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
  for (int i = 1; i < max; ++i)
    for (int j = 1; j < i; ++j)
      getVariations(MakeList(i), j).Count();
  timer.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("{0,40}{1} ms", getVariations.Method.Name, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

// Make a list that repeats to guarantee we have duplicates
public static IList<int> MakeList(int size)
{
  return Enumerable.Range(0, size/2).Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, size - size/2)).ToList();
}
```

Unoptimized

```
GetVariations                           11894 ms
GetVariationsWithoutDuplicates          9 ms
OtherAnswerGetVariations                22485 ms
OtherAnswerGetVariationsWithDuplicates  243415 ms
```

With compiler optimizations

```
GetVariations                           9667 ms
GetVariationsWithoutDuplicates          8 ms
OtherAnswerGetVariations                19739 ms
OtherAnswerGetVariationsWithDuplicates  228802 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correct here is what you need

this will create permutations based on the specified chain limit

```
    public static List<List<T>> GetPerms<T>(List<T> list, int chainLimit)
    {
        if (list.Count() == 1)
            return new List<List<T>> { list };
        return list
            .Select((outer, outerIndex) =>
                        GetPerms(list.Where((inner, innerIndex) => innerIndex != outerIndex).ToList(), chainLimit)
            .Select(perms => (new List<T> { outer }).Union(perms).Take(chainLimit)))
            .SelectMany<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>, List<T>>(sub => sub.Select<IEnumerable<T>, List<T>>(s => s.ToList()))
            .Distinct(new PermComparer<T>()).ToList();
    }

    class PermComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
    {
        public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y)
        {
            return x.SequenceEqual(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj)
        {
            return (int)obj.Average(o => o.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
```

and you'll call it like this

```
 List<List<AdServer.Offers>> lst = GetPerms<AdServer.Offers>(offers, 2);
```

I made this function is pretty generic so you may use it for other purpose too

eg

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>(new[] { "apple", "banana", "orange", "cherry" });
    List<List<string>> perms = GetPerms<string>(list, 2);
```

result

[image: permutation sample]