# c# permutation without repetition when order is important

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation

I want to get the permutations from a List of strings without repetition. I have a working code for that:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int count)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (count == 1)
                yield return new T[] { item };
            else
            {
                foreach (var result in GetPermutations(items.Skip(i + 1), count - 1))
                    yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(result);
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }


var list = new List<string> { "17", "33", "22", "32", "24", "210", "35" };
        var result = GetPermutations(list, 5);
        foreach (var perm in result)
        {
            foreach (var c in perm)
            {
                another_list.Add(c);
            }
        }
```

With an input of 7 strings and a length of 5, I get 21 results, but I actually want a result of 2520 combined strings. From a mathematical point of view, I know that the order is the factor that makes the difference here. The problem is that I don't know a way to implement the order into my code or other code that I found on the web.

Comment: You are not getting permutations in my opinion. You are getting combinations. Hence C(7,5) = 21.

Comment: If you're looking for variations (permutations with limited length), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349443/c-sharp-list-permutations-with-limited-length/24350459#24350459) might help.

Comment: @AnotherUser Not a power set, no.

Comment: @user3868224 You *are* searching for variations, at least how you've stated your question. Variations are ways of arranging k elements from a set of n elements. (As opposed to combinations, which are ways to arrange all n elements from a set of n elements, and combinations, ways of choosing k elements from a set of n elements, where order doesn't matter)

Comment: Well english isnt easy. variations, permutations, combinations hard to see the difference. So I guess I need variations, with the right words to search i may find something, thank you.

Comment: @user3868224 The linked duplicate should solve your problem...

Comment: will try this one out. how do you handle it one this board, should i delete my question?

Comment: I should have said "as opposed to permutations ... " first. Oops. And no, the usual thing to do is to leave it here; it might help future Google searchers.